# What is an "ASCII quotation mark"?

Tags: csv, character-encoding, ascii

I was working with CSV files and the program says it accepts "ASCII quotation marks". I did some research regarding character sets, but I still don't get it.
Does "ASCII quotation mark" refer to U+0022 (the vertical quotation mark) in any file, or a quotation mark in a file that has charset ASCII?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is plausible; People do often call the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) codepoints, "ASCII".

The second is less likely; the ASCII character set and character encoding are mostly used in very specialized contexts, which very often have clear standards.

This is an area where we have accepted very unclear requirements and documentation, and use language very sloppily. Text files are for experts with a competency in communication.